# Querying a SequelizeJs Many-to-Many Relationship with Multiple Parameters

Tags: javascript, api, express, mariadb, sequelize.js

## Help with querying a many to many relationship in SequelizeJs.

### Models :

#### Pers (Which represents a user):

```
const {DataTypes, Model} = require('sequelize');
const Categorie = require('./categorie_model');
const Departement = require('./departement_model');
const sequelize = require('../src/db_conn');

class Pers extends Model {}

Pers.init({
  // Attributs
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  nom: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isAlpha: {
        msg: "Le nom ne doit contenir que des lettres",
      },
      len: {
        args: [2,30],
        msg: "Le nom doit contenir entre 2-30 caractères",
      },
      notEmpty: {
        msg: "Vous devez fournir un nom",
      }
    }
  },
  prenom: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isAlpha: {
        msg: "Le prénom ne doit contenir que des lettres",
      },
      len: {
        args: [2,30],
        msg: "Le prénom doit contenir entre 2-30 caractères",
      },
      notEmpty: {
        msg: "Vous devez fournir un prénom",
      }
    }
  },
  fullname: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
      return this.nom + ' ' + this.prenom;
    },
  },
  fonction_1: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  tel_1: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  tel_2: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  mail: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: {
        msg: "L'Email n'est pas valide",
      },
      notEmpty: {
        msg: "Vous devez fournir un Email",
      },
    }
  },
  pathToImg: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 'incognito.png',
  },
}, {sequelize,
  timestamps: false, // Disables sequilize default behaviour (See more at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#timestamps)
  createdAt: false, // Disables sequilize default behaviour (See more at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#timestamps)
});

module.exports = Pers;
```

#### Department

```
const {DataTypes, Model} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../src/db_conn');

class Departement extends Model {}

Departement.init({
// Attributs
// By default, Sequelize assumes that the default value of a column is NULL.

id: {
type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
primaryKey: true,
autoIncrement: true,
allowNull: false,
},
nomDepartement: {
type: DataTypes.STRING,
allowNull: false,
},
}, {sequelize,
timestamps: false, // Disables sequilize default behaviour (See more at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#timestamps)
createdAt: false, // Disables sequilize default behaviour (See more at https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#timestamps)
});

module.exports = Departement;
```

#### Relationship

```
Pers.belongsToMany(Categorie, {through: 'cat_pers'});
Pers.belongsToMany(Departement, {through: 'dep_pers'});
Categorie.belongsToMany(Pers, {through: 'cat_pers'});
Departement.belongsToMany(Pers, {through: 'dep_pers'});
```

If i'm not mistaken they are setup correctly to be in a many to many relationship.

### The problem

The query i want to build allows for 3 parameters :

- `nom` (The lastname of the user)
- `prenom` (The firstname of the user)
- `DepartmentId` (A valid id of a Department)

All of them can be "undefined" or not.

I have made this function and it works fine when i don't give it the parameter `DepartmentId`

```
exports.findAllLike =  async (req, res) => {
  searchQuery = req.query;

  try{

    const persList = await Pers.findAll({
      where: {
        nom: {[Op.like]: searchQuery.nom + '%'},
        prenom: {[Op.like]: searchQuery.prenom + '%'}
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Departement,
          where: {
            id: {[Op.like]:searchQuery.DepartementId + '%'}
          },
          through: {attributes: []},
        },
        Categorie,
      ],
    });
    res.send({
      status: true,
      data: persList
    });
  }catch(error){
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

Result :

```
"data": [
        {
            "fullname": "LESDEUXFAUX FANANA",
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "LESDEUXFAUX",
            "prenom": "FANANA",
            "fonction_1": "tech B",
            "tel_1": "02 41 68 13 01",
            "tel_2": null,
            "mail": "francois.bouju@u-lemans.fr",
            "pathToImg": "test.png",
            "Departements": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nomDepartement": "Genie Mecanique et Productique"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "nomDepartement": "Mesures Physique"
                }
            ],
            "Categories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nomCategorie": "Enseigant",
                    "cat_pers": {
                        "updatedAt": "2023-05-22T21:55:42.000Z",
                        "PerId": 1,
                        "CategorieId": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nomCategorie": "Personel BIATSS",
                    "cat_pers": {
                        "updatedAt": "2023-05-22T21:55:42.000Z",
                        "PerId": 1,
                        "CategorieId": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
```

**However if i specify the parameter `DepartementId`=2 I only 1 out of the 2 Department associated with the Model. How can i make it so that i can see all of them ?**

```
...
"Departements": [
    {
         "id": 2,
         "nomDepartement": "Gestion des Entreprise et des Administrations"
    }
],
```

I've tried reading through the sequelize Docs.